# Retrieving and playing audio file from server

Tags: javascript, php, audio

I have been trying to find a way to hide audio files (mp3) from users. I am creating a website with different permission levels and want to play specific audio files that are not stored in the webroot directory for security purposes. I don't want people to be able to visit example.com/music/mymusic.mp3 so I am storing the music before webroot. I am having troubles playing the audio file from my server. This is what im doing for test purposes.

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/php/song.php',
                success: function(text) {
                    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(text.length * 2); 
                    for(var i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
                        buf[i] = text[i];
                    }
                    console.log(buf);
                    window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
                    var context = new AudioContext();

                    context.decodeAudioData(buf, function(buffer) {
                          var source = context.createBufferSource();
                          source.buffer = buffer;
                          source.connect(context.destination);
                          source.start(0);
                    }, console.log('fail'));
            }
```

(note the mp3 im retrieving is still in the webroot directory because I am just trying to get this to play before changing the directory)

This calls song.php

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/school_bell.mp3");
?>
```

I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Unable to decode audio data" Is this because I am not properly creating an arraybuffer for my audio data? Should I create the arraybuffer in php or is sending it via a string and changing it to an arraybuffer in javascript fine? Also, are there any other possibilities to storing my mp3 files? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `song.php` doesn't send proper headers, it is like you'd open .mp3 file in a Notepad - it wouldn't be played. Sending correct headers informs the browser that the data you are sending is actually a media file. Here's an example:

```
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/school_bell.mp3'));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="school_bell.mp3"');
readfile($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/school_bell.mp3');
```

Note the usage of `readfile()` - it will read the file directly to the output buffer instead of reading it to the memory and then echoing it.

Comment: After applying your suggestions I am able to play the audio file directly by visiting example.com/song.php but i still get the same errors when loading the webpage that calls song.php. Does this mean i'm not properly converting the file to an array buffer? Is there a way to play the file using web audio api without having to convert it?